# error with hrule and arraystretch

Tags: tables

When trying to produce a table with `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}` I get an error that I cannot put an `\hrule` there.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
        \hline 
        Temperature & \SI{80}{\celsius} & \SI{120}{\celsius} & \SI{150}{\celsius} \\ 
        \hline 
        Time & \SI{3}{\hour} & \SI{15}{\minute} & \SI{5}{\minute} \\ 
        \hline 
    \end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

The code compiles without errors when removing the `renewcommand` bit. Any idea how to get it to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to apply the new arraystretch only to this particular table, you could use one of the following methods:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} 
        \hline 
        Temperature & \SI{80}{\celsius} & \SI{120}{\celsius} & \SI{150}{\celsius} \\ 
        \hline 
        Time & \SI{3}{\hour} & \SI{15}{\minute} & \SI{5}{\minute} \\ 
        \hline 
    \end{tabular}}


\bigskip

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} 
        \hline 
        Temperature & \SI{80}{\celsius} & \SI{120}{\celsius} & \SI{150}{\celsius} \\ 
        \hline 
        Time & \SI{3}{\hour} & \SI{15}{\minute} & \SI{5}{\minute} \\ 
        \hline 
    \end{tabular}
\endgroup

\bigskip

\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} 
        \hline 
        Temperature & \SI{80}{\celsius} & \SI{120}{\celsius} & \SI{150}{\celsius} \\ 
        \hline 
        Time & \SI{3}{\hour} & \SI{15}{\minute} & \SI{5}{\minute} \\ 
        \hline 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```